# Extracting substring Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following string

```
[function('lookup')]
```

I want to extract the string `lookup` from the string above.

Tried doing using

```
var lookup = Regex.Match("[function('lookup')]", @"'\b\w*\b'").Value;
```

I end up getting **'lookup'** with the single quotes instead of just **lookup**.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Well yes, your pattern includes the quotes. Why would you expect it *not* to include the quotes? You could either just strip them off the front and back, or put a capturing group inside the quotes.

Comment: If I remove the quotes I end up with `function`. Is there a better way to directly extract out `lookup` ?

Comment: No, I mean remove the quotes from the *result*. But yes, you could use a capturing group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
var lookup = Regex.Match("[function('lookup')]", @"'\b(\w*)\b'").Groups[1].Value;
```